# CakePHP - query is name of model function

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Controller:

```
<?php
class VideosController extends ForumAppController {

    /**
     * Controller Name
     * @access public
     * @var string
     */
    public $name = 'Videos';


    public function index() {
        $videos = $this->Video->getVideos();
        $this->set('videos', $videos);
    }

    public function beforeFilter() {    
        parent::beforeFilter();

        $this->Auth->allow('*');

        if (isset($this->params['admin'])) {
            $this->Toolbar->verifyAdmin();
            $this->layout = 'admin';
        }       
        $this->Security->validatePost = false;
        $this->set('menuTab', 'videos');
    }

}

?>
```

Model:

```
<?php
class Video extends ForumAppModel {

    public $name = 'Video';

    function getVideos() {

        $vids = $this->find('all', array (
            'order'     =>  array('Video.id DESC')
        ));

      return $vids;
    }

}

?>
```

I get an error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: VideosController::$Video [CORE/plugins/forum/controllers/videos_controller.php, line 13]
```

If I do

```
$this->loadModel('video');
```

I get an error:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'getVideos' at line 1 [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 549]
**Query: getVideos**
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: If I remove the table videos I get an error "Error: Database table videos for model Video was not found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code appears to be correct but it seems like CakePHP isn't trying to load the model from the right place. You can specify the model to load using the $uses variable in your controller.

Because you're using a plugin, you need to add the name of the plugin in front of the model.

```
$uses = array('Forum.Video');
```

CakePHP should handle this on it's own but some older version of CakePHP had a bug that prevented this from working properly. It appears to be fixed in 1.3.10.

For more details about the $uses variable, see http://book.cakephp.org/view/961/components-helpers-and-uses.

Comment: I checked and triple checked this... I also deleted the cache directory and turned up debugging. I deleted the model file and got the same behavior. :(

Comment: Where are the files located? Can you provide the full path relative to your application folder?

Comment: /plugins/forum/controllers/videos_controller.php
/plugins/forum/models/video.php

I have a similar model that I basically copy/pasted from. Name of the table is: videos

Comment: That's exactly how I set it up here when I tested it for you. I copied the content of your controller and models into their respective files and access them by typing http://example.org/forum/videos. No problems. The only different is that I commented out the beforeFilter part of the controller but I doubt that would have introduced the problem.

Comment: Can you try this: in the controller, add `$uses = array('Forum.Video');` and see if that solves the problem? It's somewhat similar to the solution proposed by @simpleman except that it specifies the name of the plugin.

Comment: Francois, I'd like to accept your comment if you reposted it as an answer, along with possibly an explanation why explicitly declaring the $uses (when it should be implied) variable with the model name would fix this problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The $name variable is controller name, not model name controller uses,

try this

```
$uses = "Videos"
```

Comment: CakePHP automatically set the $uses variable for you based on the name of the controller. It basically removes the "Controller" suffix and makes that the default $uses value. The only time you'd want to change uses if you want to load more or different models or non at all.